# Get just created model instance with all its subrelations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have an `Order`, `Product`, `ProductOption` and `OrderProductOption` model.

Product.php:

```
    public function product_options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductOption::class);
    }
```

A product can have multiple options, for ex. `Product` 'Shirt 1' can have `ProductOption` 'XS', 'S', 'M' etc.

ProductOption.php:

```
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'order_product_option', 'option_id', 'order_id')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
```

Order.php:

```
    public function product_options()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProductOption::class, 'order_product_option', 'order_id', 'option_id')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
```

Now, whenever an `Order` is created, I get the `Order` with its `ProductOption` relation. However, I would also like to retrieve the `Product`, thats related to `ProductOption`. I guess I can say that I would like to get a subrelation.

How can I get the just created `Order` with ALL its relations, including subrelations?

Normally, I can do:

```
return new OrderResource(Order::where('id', $order_id)
    ->with('product_options', 'product_options.product')
    ->firstOrFail());
```

But in this case, I want to return an `Order` instance, **not** `OrderRequest array`.

I tried:

```
    $order->with('product_options.product')
```

Or:

```
    $order->with('product_options.product')->get()
```

But these return a `Builder` instance or a `Collection` instance.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to use with() on an already loaded model. You have the model you want, you just need to [load](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) the relations. This is called lazy eager loading.

```
    $order->load('product_options.product')
```